# Newbie trying to compiling: some was not declare in this scope

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-construction, glut

I'm trying to compile this program:

http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/src/md2loader.zip

I'm using `g++ -c Main.cpp` but I'm getting several errors of type :

> Main.cpp:776: error: ‘glutSpecialFunc’ was not declared in this scope

Any idea?

Comment: Do not just post a link to a .zip. Post some actual code that doesn't work.

Comment: Not without going to an external website, downloading a file, unzipping it, and examining the contents.

Comment: @Mahesh: Those problems would cause a fatal error (included file not found).  His error indicated that no attempt was made to include the header file.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Exactly. My bad.

Comment: @user248959 Please accept an answer provided.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

or

```
#include <openglut.h>
```

The documentation for [`glutSpecialFunction`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutspecialfunc) tells you this.

Comment: But there is written #include <GL/glut.h> in Main.cpp. And that file is in root_of_project/include/GL/glut.h.

Comment: @user: Which GLUT distribution are you using?  According to the documentation I found (and linked to) you need `#include <openglut.h>`.

Comment: I googled "openglut.h download" and there is not information. Are your sure you mean openglut.h?

Comment: @user: Did you read [the linked man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutspecialfunc)?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a quick look at the zip you linked.

Why are you not using "make".

Makefiles have been included.  all you probably need to do is execute 'make' where you're executing g++

The reason you're getting that error is that the Main.cpp is trying to include the glut headers but they're not found.

The Makefile will set those locations for compilation

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing an `#include <glutfile.h>` in `Main.cpp` or your header files are outdated or too new for the program.